# Auto Increment By Group

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I search everywhere. I don't find my want.

I want table_schema like this:

[image]

Comment: What is your original data?

Comment: Its my products. Im grouping products on color. Because product image name is example 33.jpg But 34. product is same same product same picture different size.  Forgive me my english to bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you really want, then, is another table.  You want one table for the `grp` and another for the name.

The `grp` table would have an id (let's call it `grp_id`), which is included in the `name` name.  This id can be an auto-incremented integer.  It would also have the name of the group.

The `name` table would have an id (let's call it `name_id`).  This would also be an auto-incremented integer.  This would have the name of the animal.  You would need to join to the `grp` table to get the name of the group.